# Is there an R function which can assign values to object 'val'

Tags: r

I am trying to predict the values of missing column in the data set which I am using. I have divided my data in two separate data sets and have performed data prep and them. After that when I try to predict and run the following code

```
val.pred=predict(fit,newdata=val)
errors=val$Price-val.pred
errors**2 %>% mean() %>% sqrt()"
```

I get the following error

> "Error in predict.lm(fit, newdata = val) : object 'val' not found"

Comment: `val` just doesn't exist, what do you expect it to be ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I think the error occurred when OP **tried** to create `val.pred`

Comment: Oh I think get the misunderstanding, giving a value to `new_data` doesn't create a new object, `newdata` is described in the doc as "An optional data frame in which to look for variables with which to predict. If omitted, the fitted values are used."